# Why is my PHP script not being executed when calling it by AJAX JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to execute a PHP script on a button click, which downloads an image from a URL to my server, through AJAX JQuery.

Here is the AJAX code in the .html file:

In the head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the body section:

```
<button type="button" id="btntest">Test PHP</button>

<script>
    $("#btntest").on('click',function(){
        alert("start");
        var data = {"image-url" : "/serverfolder/Image.png","path" : "https://example.com/Image.png"};
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "test.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(resultData) { alert("success"); }
       });
    });
</script>
```

The code in the test.php file:

```
<?php
$params = $_POST['data'];
$path = $params['path'];
$image_url = $params['image-url'];
    
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$new = $image_url;
file_put_contents($new, fopen($data, 'r'));
?>
```

The problem: I don't get the "success" alert, instead I get an Internal server error for the test.php file. If test.php file only looks like this:

```
<?php
$params = $_POST['data'];
$path = $params['path'];
$image_url = $params['image-url'];
?>
```

The success alert appears, but that doesn't help me, because I want to download the file from the $path to the server directory $image_url. Any help appreciated on how to get this to work.

Comment: Display all PHP errors level to get the error message.

Comment: A 500/Internal Server error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Shouldn't the assignment to `$params` be more like `$params = json_decode($_POST['data'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send data in ajax like that

```
data:{data:data}
```

that is ok
or you can send data like

```
data:{image_url : "/serverfolder/Image.png",path : "https://example.com/Image.png"}
```

in this shape you dont need to decode in php file and use like it

```
$path = $_POST['path']; 
$image_url = $_POST['image_url'];
```

THAT'S IT